# Redirect on button click not working on live site

Tags: javascript

So I am a newbie at JS and am trying to force this [submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY4HT.png) to redirect to a specific page on our website. I have tested out the following code (below) which works on JSFiddle, but when I add the same JS to the live site it's not working.

Any help here is greatly appreciated!

```
<button id="btnSubmit" class="float-left submit-button" value="3">Home</button>
    
document.getElementById("btnSubmit").onclick = function() {window.location.href = "https://moralesgroup.net/";
};
```

https://jsfiddle.net/28p1ek0m/#&togetherjs=F3pwv9yV68

[where i'm allowed to edit on the backend of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDysc.png)

Comment: the closing bracket didn't format correctly, which is why it's showing in between the js code and jsfiddle link

Comment: But your JS Fiddle works perfectly, what's the problem?

Comment: Also you can simply encapsulate your button in a link. Same result without JS.

Comment: so i can't do that because i don't have access to edit the html on the buttons. i can only add in javascript code and with the jsfiddle working, i'm not sure where else to go – Andy Erk just now   Edit   Delete

Comment: It's not the same code. On your screenshot here are weird double quotes around `btnSubmit`. These probably don't work in Javascript. Use regular double quotes. Doesn't your console complain about a syntax error or something??

Comment: correct. i didn't share the most recent screenshot of the jsfiddle in the box. my apologies there. i was trying to show that i can't edit html directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
  <button>
        <a href="https://moralesgroup.net/" >Home</a>
  </button>
```

Check this example https://jsfiddle.net/y0mfqpd7/1/

Comment: so i can't do that because i don't have access to edit the html buttons. i can only add in javascript code and with the jsfiddle working, i'm not sure where else to go

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wait until the document is loaded before you can run this code. Kind of like here: [Pure JavaScript equivalent of jQuery's $.ready() - how to call a function when the page/DOM is ready for it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899372/pure-javascript-equivalent-of-jquerys-ready-how-to-call-a-function-when-t)

```
function docReady(fn) {
    // see if DOM is already available
    if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
        // call on next available tick
        setTimeout(fn, 1);
    } else {
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
    }
}

docReady(function() {
    document.getElementById("btnSubmit").onclick = function() {window.location.href = "https://moralesgroup.net/";
});
```

Also, make sure all of this is either in a `<script>` tag at the bottom of the page, or in a .js file loaded in the head.

Comment: Thanks! I attempted this method with no luck. Seems like something wonky with the actual application. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would do like Ahmed Ibrahim said, except I would wrap the button in an anchor tag, otherwise the edges of the button are not clickable:

```
  <a href="https://moralesgroup.net/">
    <button>
      Home
    </button>
  </a>
```

However when I do this I get a small hyperlink underline to the right of the button for some reason, but this can be fixed with `text-decoration: none` in css:

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: so i can't do that because i don't have access to edit the html buttons. i can only add in javascript code and with the jsfiddle working, i'm not sure where else to go

Comment: @AndyErk So Your code works in my live server, but only if the JavaScript is loaded _after_ the button is loaded.Maybe their JS that you have access to is loaded at the top of the page for some reason? (Seems odd to me). Try this: ```window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function() {
    location.href = "https://moralesgroup.net/thanks-employee/";
  };
})

``` This works despite placement of JS. Function now waits for window load completion to execute. I think same principle @PawelKowaluk mentioned

Comment: so i went and implemented your recommended code with no luck still. i appreciate your help!

Comment: @AndyErk I'm sure you did this, but the id of the button in my code needs to be changed to the correct id of your button (```btnSubmit``` i believe)

Comment: welp, I own the fact that I completely whiffed on that. Let me make sure i change things correctly and report back. my bad for that

Comment: so i tried your method a few different times with no luck still. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can directly go to the new window on click of a button by below code:

```
<button id="btnSubmit" class="float-left submit-button" value="3" href="https://moralesgroup.net/">Home</button>
```

Here, I have used the button tag, given the same id as yours, and used the same class to have the same styling as you wanted. `href` will directly redirect to the new link which has been provided in quotes.

Comment: so i can't do that because i don't have access to edit the html buttons. i can only add in javascript code and with the jsfiddle working, i'm not sure where else to go